# Robocopy non administrator

Tags: robocopy

Can I run Robocopy with a non administrator user if I have read/write rights on both source and destination folders? Is there any side effect/limitation?

My command would be:

```
robocopy \\server1\SRC \\server2\DEST
```

THANKS!

Comment: Seems not to be programming related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work if you have the permissions.  If you want to mirror subfolders then add the /MIR option.